# Sprite background - inline nested? (html frozen)

Tags: css

Here's another CSS changes only question. [
Demonstrated here

So, I have a background sprite for some styling elements, and want to style textfields with endcaps (TEXTFIELD) and a repeating background. I've lined things up using padding spaces here in the example, which lets me set background-color, but not a background I think. I've been staring at this for too long, and need some advice. Is it possible to line things up the way I want them, without changing the HTML?

```
<label> Enter Zipcode: </label>
<span class='bg'>
    <span class='leftcap'>
        <span class='rightcap'>
           <input type="text" class="textfield" name="zipCode" />
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

edit: I'm spitting angry over here, somehow lost my jsfiddle, and gar.  My question still stands... the other jsfiddle linked shared a couple similarities, and served as a base, but I ended up changing almost everything by the time I had it set up. Good thing I copied a little over here.

edit2: here is a partial remade jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/dreamling/P3Jev/3/

Comment: "I've lined things up using padding spaces here in the example, which lets me set background-color, but not a background I think." - I don't understand, you can set whatever background you like. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/P3Jev/4/

Comment: @thirtydot Wow, ok, haha. I got close. ok, how do I make the endcaps the same size as the bg? I keep increasing the height, but nothing happens.  (Thanks for being so patient)

Comment: it seems that the textbox is not entirely inside the box of the span that is rightcap, I can't seem to m ake rightcap or leftcap a little taller. I can make leftcap much taller, say 50px, but that breaks the box, instead of expanding it.

Answer (score 1):

- I changed outer2 to display:inline-block, that fixes it.
- The strange gaps are there because inline-block elements are whitespace dependend (and a whitespace is exactly 4px at standard font-size)
- Fix: add letter-spacing:-4px + line-height: 1px.

See http://jsfiddle.net/L8TyD/6/

EDIT: i removed the fixed width, and added hack to make it work in ie7

Comment: The magic sentence, hidden in the JavaScript panel of her jsFiddle demo, is "can the goal be achieved without fixed sizes". There shouldn't be a fixed width on `.b`, as I understand it.

Comment: @thirtydot as far as i understood, dreamling especially didn't want fixed width on the outer element, as in your answer. Anyway, i removed the widths and updated my answer.

Comment: sorry, ignore the js, I tried to delete it. but I'll look at any solution.